How to Access Kafka Broker Running in Docker on WSL2 from Windows Host?
I have a straightforward Kafka broker running on WSL2 with this docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  broker:
    image: apache/kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,CONTROLLER://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@localhost:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3

It works as long as I am inside the container, but I would like to access the broker from outside. I use 'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092' from my Windows machine (I'm using a simple Python script to do it), and I get a connection refusal: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 2054ms in state CONNECT).
I also tried with the WSL IP (even though it is not ideal; I want to spread this with my team, and everybody will have a different IP), but it doesn't work.
I think I need to expose the broker to the Windows host, but I couldn't understand how.
Thanks

You need to first add ports to the compose file. Then, you must remove localhost from KAFKA_LISTENERS since that explicitly defines no external connections will be allowed. Use KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093 to start.
And if that doesn't work, you'll need to use the netsh command to port forward the hypervisor to the windows network interface
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4
